# Localization not working on Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, windows-10

I have Winforms app that is 100% working on Win 7 and 8. One of my projects is for localizing strings.
The code below returns a "default" (en) localized string, not the one set in the app code. I was debugging and came to this line, that is not working:

```
public static string ITEM_TYPE {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("ITEM_TYPE", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

resourceCulture is CultureInfo value which is properly set ("sr-Latn-CS" - Serbian Latin).

Comment: Maybe your exe-file is not able to find satellites for some reasons? Check folder structure is it the same on windows 10? Maybe installer is a problem?

Comment: I've just upgraded to Windows 10. This is my developer machine, I am testing my app with Visual Studio 2013, everything was working few hours ago on Windows 8.1.

Comment: So you are building project. Try to clean it and rebuild again and then again inspect satellites (are they created?). Btw, this could be a some issue with VS2013, it's not listed to be [compatible](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx) with Windows 10. Would you mind to start using shiny VS 2015?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997383%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#new_specific_cultures

Comment: Thanks Hans, I also read this yesterday, I just wanted to make sure that this was causing a problem. I think that the combination of .NET 4 and Windows 10 causes the app not be able to interpret 'sr-Latn-CS' code. I made it work when I put RS instead of CS.